# How to create a matrix with dynamic rows and columns in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, matrix

I have to make a control in ASP.NET that allows me to create a matrix. I have a list of strings (obtained from a method) that will be the rows (each string is one row), and I have another list of strings (obtained from other method) that will be the columns (each string is one column). After that, depending on the row-cloumn cross I have to put an image in that position, something like this:

```
       x  |  y |  z
   a | OK | OK | BAD|
   ------------------
   b | OK |BAD | OK |
   ------------------
   c |BAD |BAD | BAD|
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)s.

The outer repeater for rows, the inner one for columns/cells.